# Организация работы 1С-предприятия в сети и вопрос лицензирования Windows Server

Tags: 1с, windows-server, rdp

Устроился в небольшую фирму админом, парк компов в сети ~25. В сети есть сервер на WinServ2003, пиратский, работает терминальный сервер через который все пользователи работают с 1ской (лицензий на сервер терминалов тоже нет). 1Ска на файловой бд, версия 8.3 (вроде).

Встал вопрос о лицензировании серверной винды. Соответственно ценник с учетом RDS-лицензий на компы немалый, в связи с чем вытекает вопрос о возможных аналогах:

1. Будет ли выгоден переход на 1С SQL версию, отказаться от терминального сервера (насколько я понимаю, с файловой бд это не выгодно точно), так чтобы не появился значительный ущерб в производительности?
2. Был вариант с Linux'ом, но повозившись с местными RDP и подводными камнями по типу непереключаемой раскладки и отсутствием драйверов принтеров для локальной печати в терминальной сессии, желание перехода на Linux пока отпало. Но, может где-то можно почитать статью о простой настройке терминалки на Linux'e, так чтобы это не вызывало проблем у юзеров?
3. Возможно есть какие-то другие варианты?

Answer (score 0):

Можно сделать так:

- linux - server DB - PostgreSQL
- linux - server 1C
- linux - license manager 1C
- windows - компьютеры пользователей (с принтерами)

---

**Выгода:** сэкономите на лицензиях на серверную венду, RDP к ней и SQL сервер.

**Недостаток:** ущерб в производительности будет, но небольшой, в пределах 10-15% - это разница между MS-SQL и PostgreSQL (последний раз эксперименты ставил лет 10 назад - проверьте сами на всякий случай), а разница между файловой версией и PostgreSQL будет наоборот, т.к. SQL по-любому быстрее - заметно будет сразу на отчетах..

Comment: Сейчас разница в производительности, если и есть, то небольшая, плюс, зависит от ряда факторов.

Comment: Да, тут даже и не спорю. В комментарии подразумевал Postgre vs MS

Answer (score 0):

У нас в бухгалтерии, насколько я знаю, принята другая схема:

- Головной Windows Server 2012 (но там в своё время они раздавались
  бесплатно, что сейчас - не знаю, не наблюдаю за этой сферой несколько
  лет). На нём крутится 1С.
- Сервер БД на Ubuntu - прямой кросс-линк к
  серверу 1С
- Рабочие машины и неттопы на Ubuntu (работа в 1С
  осуществляется через удалённый доступ).
- Принтеры и прочая оргтехника    - сетевые.

Тут наоборот: вы заплатите за сервер (вряд ли уже MS будет щедра), но есть тонкости с лицензированием удаленных рабочих столов для Linux (покупался самый оптимальный по цене вариант).

Comment: @Drakonoved Про веб-клиент не знал, могу сообщить админам, хотя, возможно, они и знают :) Но то, что Postgre бегает на Ubuntu, а 1С - на WinServer2012 - 100%, сам видел

Comment: @Drakonoved Зашёл к админам, переспросил, ответили: "Именно 1 Сервер". В описанной мной конфигурации.

Comment: веб клиент не применим в данном случае, как сказал 1Сник, ибо бух2.0 не работает в нем. Соответственно этот вариант отклоняется

Comment: @kleshenki Так веб-клиент не нужен, если идти по пути удаленного доступа. Кстати, 2.0 работает с тонким клиентом, но самому придётся писать формы, редко кто это любит. Впрочем, я давно отошёл от всего :) этого

Comment: @Drakonoved Примерно знаю, - в не очень хорошие годы приходилось. Зато не нужно покупать новую версию. В целом, в ответах и комментариях вам предложили минимум 3 варианта развития событий. Да, "ленивого" среди них нет. Выбрать ли какой-то, скомбинировать или пойти собственным путём, - решать вам.